# Partitioning Views in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, indexed-views

How do I partition an Indexed View in MS-SQL ? I have a index view created which stores range of values. The view definition is as follows

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.target_individual_product WITH SCHEMABINDIN       
    AS SELECT day_dim.date_time AS Date,  
    SUM(ISNULL(order_dim.quantity,0)) AS Target_Acheived,  
    branch_dim.branch_name AS Branch_Name ,   
    product_dim.product_name AS Product_Name  
FROM dbo.day_dim INNER JOIN  
     dbo.order_fact ON day_dim.day_id = order_fact.day_id  
INNER JOIN dbo.product_dim ON order_fact.product_id = product_dim.product_id   
INNER JOIN dbo.branch_dim ON order_fact.branch_id = branch_dim.branch_id   
INNER JOIN dbo.order_dim ON order_fact.order_id = order_dim.order_id  
GROUP BY order_dim.quantity, day_dim.date_time,branch_dim.branch_name, product_dim.product_name  
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX target_individual_product_I on target_individual_product (Date)
```

Now i want to partition this table using date column. How do I do that ?

Comment: Could you display your SQL in a more readable way and without spelling errors? If you can do it in your code, you can surely do it on Stack Overflow ;)

Comment: Here's a nice article that describes partitioning an indexed view: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/partition/64740/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be looking for a "partition-aligned" index; partitioning is supported in SQL 2008 Enterprise Edition (you didn't mention your version or edition). Partitioned indexes are discussed in Books Online, but there is no discussion of partitioning view indexes that I can find, although it is possible and it's described in a white paper here (see query 11 at the end of the paper):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921.aspx

Comment: Hah, you found the same example :)

Comment: Thank you!! I am using 2008 version. If there is no facility for creating on views then tel me how do i partition a table categorizing by text values. For example "text1,text2,text2" so content with text1 should go to partition1  and text2 into partition2 ...

Comment: Follow a good tutorial. For example: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/partitioned-tables-in-sql-server-2005/

Answer (score 2):

I have little experience with partitioning, but I think you are confusing things.
(Gurus, please correct me if I'm wrong).

As far as I know there are [three types of partitioning in SQL Server](http://www.novicksoftware.com/presentations/sql-server-partitioning/Partitioning-Tables-Views-and-Indexed-Views.htm):

A **partitioned table** can be partitioned on a column such as date.

A **partitioned view** is a view specifying a `UNION` between similar queries from different tables.

A **partioned-aligned indexed view** is an indexed view that is partitioned along the same column(s) as the partitioned table to which it is linked.

I don't think it is possible to partition an indexed view without partitioning the underlying table. Therefore, I would suggest that you partition your `day_dim` on the `date_time` column, and then create a partition-aligned indexed view to match this column. See [this link and scroll down to Query 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx) for an example how to do this.

Comment: thanks for that!! if you could help me with indexing it would be very nice. Is there any equivalent for bitmap indexing in sql ?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. But Google knows: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatawarehousing/thread/3b7fc3a0-32e2-4c73-99c1-1357ebcc4753